# Do we need to put cement on all sides of bricks when building house walls?

Tags: walls, cement, building

I have started building walls on my house and I have noticed that the builder in the third row just put the bricks next to each other without any cement in between at all?

just to note the first three rows will be filed with sand inside.

I am not expert and this is my first house to build and I am managing my self to learn from experience. but it looks so wrong to me!

here are some pictures of the third row I am talking about .

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Not a brick layer, but if finished like that I would have concerns.  You said sand is to be filled in, so might just be putting them in place for now, remove to fill sand then finish.

Comment: I was taught to do hem like tile back butter the sides and bottom then they will stick better and be stronger. But I have not made entire houses fire places , but I would think the same reasoning would apply.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to indicate where in the world you are. Also, since building practices do vary around the world, look at other houses and/or check with other builders to ensure that this is the standard in your area. If there's a building/construction inspector, be sure to ask him to look at this, too.

Answer (score 3):

This might be some locally appropriate technology to provide drainage or venting for the (under the interior floor, I'm guessing) sand fill (since this does not seem likely to be "fill between bricks in wall sand fill" given how that's laid up.)

It's not a common method in this area, but it may be a standard practice local to you. You could ask your builder why, or look at other houses local to you.

There are "similar but different" details in brick walls locally, such as the use of weep holes that are basically gaps in the mortar joints to let water out of double-brick walls.

When traveling I've seen many different ways to build a house. The details are often quite different in different locations, and sometimes the reasons for those difference are not obvious at first glance.

Comment: totally agree with you, i am building house in Azerbaijan and I am from yemen, two different ways of constructing.